# Do constant fields in ROS2 topics affect serialized message size?

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, performance

If I define a ROS2 field as [constant](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Concepts/About-ROS-Interfaces.html#constants), does the on-the-wire size of a serialized message change? In other words, do constant fields affect the serialized representation of ROS2 messages?

PS I am using the default middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Looking at the binary data for a `visualization_msgs/msg/Marker` message saved with `ros2 bag`, the values of the constants don't appear in the message data. If you inspect the generated code for an interface, you may also notice that only fields are part of the message structure, constants are only defined in the api/header files.